# How do you make concave borders in HTML/CSS like this example?

Tags: html, css, user-interface

Here is an example graphic from mode.com, made using normal divs in a flexbox arrangement.

[image: mode.com example of non-square shapes using concave borders]

How does this happen?
By looking at the page source, I can see there are four elements in play in a row-based flexbox; the middle element in the flex includes an upper and a lower div which blend into the left and right divs.

I'm mainly curious where the rounded, concave inside borders are coming from. I had hoped to see pseudo-elements like `&:before` or `&:after` on those middle-column pieces, and there seems to be none there. The web generally is a horrible place for non-square media, so this is a curious example I'd like to include in some of my builds. Hope someone can help by digging in on the https://mode.com page source code.

Comment: The page's markup is a bit gnarly: e.g. for the main header they've got _multiple_ `<h1>` elements (one for each visible line of text) - and it's a ReactJS site - so they're probably using JS to keep the appearance updated instead of using _only_ CSS.

Comment: After some more digging I can say their approach isn't too remarkable: they're basically sticking together a bunch of normal rounded-corner elements together, then they add a bunch of `<div>` elements  with `position: absolute;` to the inner corners to make them appear as "reverse" / concave rounded corners (e.g. just-off the top-left corner of the "b" in "built around").

Comment: _"I had hoped to see pseudo-elements like &:before or &:after on those middle-column pieces, and there seems to be none there."_ - yes there are, but they put those on extra `div` elements, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWUvM.png

Comment: Ah, these responses all helped. I didn't think the pseudo-elements would be on standalone divs, and so I'd been looking at the main blocks in use in the headings and somehow missed the corresponding corners, which are somewhat dispersed in the markeup. Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reimplement their main header look, except using *only* CSS (no JS) and also only using a single `<h1>` element (compared to their *half-dozen*...):

Side-by-side comparison:

[image]

---

> I'm mainly curious where the rounded, concave inside borders are coming from
> I had hoped to see pseudo-elements like `::before` or `::after` on those middle-column pieces, and there seems to be none there.

There are - I don't know why you said you couldn't see it:

[image]

Their approach uses a solid color and `border-bottom/top-right/left-radius:` for those inverted corners, which only works when used on-top of a solid color background - whereas my approach uses `mask-image:` with a `radial-gradient` to achieve proper transparency, so my technique will work on-top of any background texture.

---

```css
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto) 100px;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
    
    outline: 1px solid red;
}

h1 > span {
    display: inline-block;
/*  outline: 1px solid blue;*/
    background-color: cyan;
    
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    
    position: relative;
}

h1 > span:nth-child(1) {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  justify-self: end;
  
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
h1 > span:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  justify-self: end;
  
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
h1 > span:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
  justify-self: end;
  
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
}

h1 > span::before,
h1 > span::after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    display: none;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    
    background-color: cyan;
    -webkit-mask-image: radial-gradient(15px at bottom left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 99%, black 99%);
    
    position: absolute;
}

h1 > span:nth-child(2)::before {
    display: inline-block;
    top: 0;
    left: -15px;
}

h1 > span:nth-child(2)::after {
    display: inline-block;
    bottom: 0;
    right: -15px;
    
    -webkit-mask-image: radial-gradient(15px at top right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 99%, black 99%);
}

h1 > span:nth-child(3)::before {
    top: 0;
    left: -15px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h1>
    <span>Dyslexia for</span>
    <span>Cure</span>
    <span>Found</span>
</h1>

<h1>
    <span>Business Intelligence</span>
    <span>built around</span>
    <span>data teams</span>
</h1>
```

---

Another approach worth looking at is implementing Metaballs using CSS shadows and filters - the articles and demos linked below are concerned mostly with free-floating/circular metaballs, as opposed to adding metaball-like "manifold" (is that the right term?) to existing rectangular HTML element boxes.

- https://blobs.webflow.io/
- https://varun.ca/metaballs/
- https://css-tricks.com/shape-blobbing-css/

This demo I'm particularly fond-of for some reason:

https://codepen.io/keithclark/pen/WNgRMQ

```css
/* From https://codepen.io/keithclark/pen/WNgRMQ */
body,
html,.wrap {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
body {
  -webkit-filter: contrast(25);
  filter: contrast(25);
  background: black;
}
.wrap {
  background: inherit;
  animation: 7s spin ease-in-out infinite;
}

.meta::before,
.meta::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  margin:-50px;
  background: rgba(160,230,245,.9);
  border-radius:50%;
  -webkit-filter: blur(25px);
  filter: blur(25px);
  animation: move 12s infinite alternate ease-in-out;

}
.meta::before {
  animation-duration: 19.3s;
  animation-delay: -3.3s;
}
.meta:nth-child(2)::before {
  animation-duration: 14.7s;
  animation-delay: -2.7s;
}
.meta:nth-child(2)::after {
  animation-duration: 8.7s;
  animation-delay: -5.32s;
}
@keyframes spin {
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg)
  }
}
@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0%, 100%);
  }
  15% {
    transform: translate(-120%, 160%);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translate(100%, -80%);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(-140%, 0%);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(40%, -80%);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(-160%, -20%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(40%, 60%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <!-- From https://codepen.io/keithclark/pen/WNgRMQ -->
  <div class="meta"></div>
  <div class="meta"></div>
</div>
```